# Javascript query not finding existing field

Tags: javascript, sobject

There is some small work going on with a custom javascript button in an org that I do not have Admin access to.  It fails on a field that clearly exists.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 
var url = parent.location.href; 
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.IFE__iQuote__c)}; 
var newRecords = []; 
var iQuoteId;

if (records[0] == null) { 
  alert("Please select at least one record to update."); 
} else if (records.length > 1){ 
  alert("Please only select one record to update"); 
} 
else
{
  var iQuote = new sforce.SObject("IFE__iQuote__c"); 
  iQuote.ID = records[0];
  iQuoteId = records[0];
  iQuote.IFE__Primary__c = true; 
  iQuote.IFE__IsWaiting__c = true;
  newRecords.push(iQuote);

  result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
  waitToCheck();
}

function waitToCheck()
{
  setTimeout(checkIsWaiting, 500);
}

function checkIsWaiting()
{
  //Error this query below?
  var records = sforce.connection.query("SELECT IFE__IsWaiting__c FROM IFE__iQuote__c WHERE Id = '" + iQuoteId + "'");
  var iQuote = records.getArray('records')[0];
  var isWaiting = iQuote.IFE__IsWaiting__c;
  if (isWaiting == 'false')
  {
    parent.location.href = url; 
  } else
  {
    waitToCheck();
  }
}
```

Would this happen if the current running User doesn't have field access to that 'IsWaiting__c' field?

EDIT:

Error

```
No such column 'IsWaiting__c' on entity 'CustomQuoteName__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.', detail:{InvalidFieldFault:{exceptionCode:'INVALID_FIELD', exceptionMessage:'
SELECT IsWaiting__c FROM CustomQuoteName__c
       ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
No such column 'IsWaiting__c' on entity 'CustomQuoteName__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.', row:'1', column:'8', }, }, }
```

Comment: In my experience you can assign values to field name for an `sforce.SObject` just as you can a plain JavaScript object i.e. no clever validation logic is added. I suspect your problem is on a different line?

Comment: @KeithC Actually, it was the wrong line.  The part I originally posted didn't seem to error oddly enough.

Comment: The answer to the question halfway through is yes. Does your profile (or the profile receiving the error) have access to that field so that can be ruled out (or confirmed) as the cause?

Comment: @AlexTennant That's what I was wondering if that gave me enough info to tell that.  I don't have enough access into the org to see this info.  This is about as much info as I was given and I can't get in there to look myself.

Comment: It's one of those great unhelpful error messages that doesn't tell you what the actual cause is, but if you're certain that the field exists then lack of access through FLS is likely the cause.

Comment: Alright thanks.  I emailed them awhile ago asking them to check that but haven't heard anything.  I was hoping that this is likely the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rather helpful error message appears for one of two reasons:

- the field doesn't exist
- the user trying to access the field does not have access to it through their Profile or a Permission Set

Since you've confirmed that the field definitely exists then it must be a permissions issue. Hopefully when you contact the administrator of the Org they will confirm this is the case and can resolve it for you.